# How can i fix SessionFactory Spring MVC error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

Please help me with this Spring MVC error java compiler says there's an error but eclipse doesn't recognize one!

[image]

This are all the libraries i am using . Not using Maven!

[image: deps]

Comment: Please add stack trace as a text. Please also provide the dependencies list (or pom if you use maven)

Comment: @SternK i uploaded all libraries i am using take a look ...